# Does async tag wrap a JavaScript function with a Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

So I understand that "async" ensures that a function will return a Promise, and if it doesn't then it wraps it in a promise.

My question is, if the function is already returning a Promise, does "async" wrap it in another Promise?

**async function, return non-Promise:**

```
async function foo() {
    return 5;
}

console.log(foo()) // Promise { 5 }
```

**regular function, return Promise:**

```
function foo() {
    return Promise.resolve(5);
}

console.log(foo()) // Promise { 5 }
```

**async function, return Promise:**

```
async function foo() {
    return Promise.resolve(5);
}

console.log(foo()) // Promise { <pending> }
```

Why does the last one return **"Promise { pending }"** ? My intuition tells me the redundant "async" tag is wrapping the already returned Promise with another Promise. Is this correct?

Comment: You have to accept that Promises are not designed to be synchronously inspected and that synchronous inspection is a bit querky. The behaviour could be, and maybe should be, more consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an `async` function returns a Promise, then the Promise returned by that function will resolve to the same value as the original Promise. This can be seen with a simple example:

```
async function foo() {
  return Promise.resolve(42);
}
console.log(await foo()); // "42", not "Promise { 42 }"
```

So in most normal situations, we can simply imagine that the Promise returned by the code inside the async function body is returned without being touched. But as you've stumbled across, even though the Promise returned by an async function will resolve to the same value as a Promise returned by the code, the actual Promise object is not necessarily the same:

```
let p1;
async function foo() {
  p1 = Promise.resolve(42);
  return p1;
}
let p2 = foo();
console.log('p1 === p2 ?', p1 === p2); // "false" (!)
```

So we can see that the Promise object returned by the function invocation is actually different from the Promise object that the function body returned. No matter, though, it will give the same result when we `await` it (or use `Promise.then()`):

```
let p1;
async function foo() {
    p1 = Promise.resolve(42);
    return p1;
}
let p2 = foo();

console.log(await p1); // '42'
console.log(await p2); // also '42'
```

(Note that to run these examples in e.g. a node repl shell, you'll need to wrap them like:

```
async function main() {
  /* code using async / await here */
}
main();
```

Comment: Thanks @MykWillis that's very helpful. 

So would it be accurate to say if an async function is already returning a Promise, then that Promise is unwrapped, to then be wrapped in a new Promise from the "async" tag?

Comment: @webbyweb I think that's a fair characterization based on these experiments, though to be honest I'm not sure if that is dictated by specification or just a particular implementation choice. But it is certainly the case that an async function that returns a promise will not end up returning a nested promise to its caller (i.e., a Promise that resolves to another Promise).

Comment: Got it, thanks! Btw I believe in your answer you mean to return p1 the second time you define "foo". I understand what you meant but just to be more clear for whoever else reads your answer to understand this question

Comment: yes, I meant to return p1, sorry about that omission. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your last function as:

```
foo.then(function(r){console.log(r)});
```

The reason being, an async function needs to return a promise. A promise will log pending until the result is resolved.  To capture the promise, you must call "then".

Here is a link for more info about then:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Here is a link for more info about async functinos:
https://fmpapidev.holstein.ca/swagger/index.html

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. In the first example why does it return "Promise { 5 }" if I'm not calling "then" ?

Comment: @webbyweb I agree this answer doesn't answer your question, but: the console is showing you "Promise { 5 }" because the object you gave to console.log is a Promise that, if you were to call .then() on it, would give you a value of 5. It just so happens that the Promise had already resolved when you printed its value, but that's because you created it with Promise.resolve(). If you had returned a non-resolved Promise, the console.log would've shown "Promise { <pending> }.

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm not certain what the native implementation of `async`/ `await` is for modern node apps but if you take a look at what `Babel` generates when it transpiles to node 6

Take this simple async function:

```
async function fooAsync() {
  return 1;
}
```

Babel transforms this code to look like this:

```js
function asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, key, arg) { try { var info = gen[key](arg); var value = info.value; } catch (error) { reject(error); return; } if (info.done) { resolve(value); } else { Promise.resolve(value).then(_next, _throw); } }

function _asyncToGenerator(fn) { return function () { var self = this, args = arguments; return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { var gen = fn.apply(self, args); function _next(value) { asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, "next", value); } function _throw(err) { asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, "throw", err); } _next(undefined); }); }; }

function fooAsync() {
  return _fooAsync.apply(this, arguments);
}

function _fooAsync() {
  _fooAsync = _asyncToGenerator(function* () {
    return 1;
  });
  return _fooAsync.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

You can see the transformation of your async method and the state machine it generates. The interesting part is that the generator, when executed, return a `new Promise()`. So to answer your question, just having the keyword `async` in your function, would make it return a `Promise`. This can also be seen in `Typescript` where the compiler will moan if you have an `async` method and you don't specify a return type of `Promise<T>`